Can i require compensation for getting vendors and training co workers and basically run the new business out of my experience alone
Ten years ago I came to work for a vendor that supplied my needs from a former employer. When I started they were not up and running they were very basic in their knowledge and bought a peice of equipment and had a single vendor. I was shown how to fill out a work order and to use the equipment in order to accomplish a task I was already familiar with but just with their equipment.
Everything else I ended up teaching my co workers such as where to find parts, what to charge in hours for jobs. I taught over and over how to check for bad parts and how to fix the problems including information that I had to pay to learn.
Over the years I taught many co workers some of which left and taught others including ways that I came up with on my own to expedite repairs and make significant profits.
If and when my usefulness for the business ends is it suggested to seek compensation?

Compensation for what?  It sounds like you've been a very good and useful employee.  The compensation for that is the salary (and benefits) you receive.  If you feel that your compensation does not reflect the value you bring to the business, ask for a raise.

From what I have read, you put in a lot of effort, but without location it would be hard to answer. In the US you would get 0, in most countries that is, you would get 0 unless the contract stated otherwise.

You can seek compensation anytime you like, but you won't likely get it from the company. They will only pay you for what they agree up front (including your salary). What you have done is the normal part of your job, which includes training and helping new employees.


If and when my usefulness for the business ends is it suggested to
seek compensation?

No, I can't think of anyone who would suggest that. You've been paid for your work regularly all along (I assume); that's called a job.
The time to seek agreement on extra compensation is at the start of a job, not at the end of a job. You can ask for a raise midway if you take on extra capacities (i.e., the job changes or evolves). But the time for negotiation is before the paycheck in question, not after.
Feel free to ask if you want, crazy stuff happens, but the chance of success is probably not worth the time spent asking. Maybe if you have some kind of other legal claim for damages or severance, but that would be a separate issue, and the case here (shared knowledge at work) doesn't remotely apply.
This does bring to mind the "plumbing story" where 99% of the charge is for the knowledge required. But note again, the fee is established before payment for service, not after.

Whenever you think you are not compensated fairly take a look at what you could make someplace else.
All the things you described sound like basically working.

I am assuming US. I am not a Lawyer. I am a business owner.
Your employer hopefully over the years has shown appreciation for your drive and skillset. If they have not, shame on them. In the same fashion, if they have left it so that you are the only person with that skillset, shame on them.
To the point of your question, if you didn't have a meeting of the minds, try not to get emotionally about it. Sit down with your employer and state your case. Please don't make threats, they NEVER end well.
Consider giving your employer sometime to think over what you brought to their attention. Remember, when there isn't a problem, nobody really notices it.
I am a random internet person that has been on the other side of this conversation. I am embarrassed to say more than once over the years. I always gave a bonus and a raise. That was me, don't expect your boss to do the same.
Another point to consider is to go forward. The past is the past.
Good luck.

"If and when your usefulness for the business ends" that is the time to take that experience and find another place to work. Seriously, from the business owner's perspective, that would be the time to fire you / lay you off.
It is actually best to look for that time approaching and when you see that, get working on finding other work.

Ask for a promotion to a "senior" role if you aren't already in that position.
In software engineering, many of the sort of mentorship tasks are expected of senior software engineers - and the ability to mentor more junior engineers is one of the marks distinguishing a senior engineer from an intermediate software engineer (and an intermediate engineer is distinguished from a junior by being able to work independently without needing memtorship).
So, if you're not already working in a "senior" role in the business (which might be called something different, depending on industry), you can go to your boss, point to the work you've done over the course of your employment, and say you're already working at that higher level before asking for a promotion and a pay raise.
